# Centre submit button in line with form box

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I have tried in vain to align my submit button to one entry of a form. I simply want the submit button to be positioned slightly to the right and centre of the form box. Presently, it is to the right but a little to the bottom of the box.

I have tried all of the different responses in answer to similar queries regarding aligning submit buttons (float, margin etc.), but for the life of me I cannot find the right option!

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="query" id="querybox" style="width:400px;height:40px;font-size:26px;border-radius:15px;border=0;">
        </input>

    <input type="button" value="Search" id="search" style="width:100px;height=40px;font-size=20px;"/>
```

The CSS to style the button looks like this:

```
    #search {
cursor:pointer; 
    width:70px; 
    height: 31px; 
    line-height:0; 
    font-size:0; 
    text-indent:-999px;
    color: transparent;  
    background: url(ico-search.png) no-repeat #151B54 center; 
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
}

#submit:hover {
    background: url(ico-search.png) no-repeat center #151B54; 
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

    }
```

Any help much appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: click the tick near the answer that helped you to Accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your inputs each in a div like so

```
<div class="vertAlign">
    <input name="query" id="querybox" style="width:400px;height:40px;font-size:26px;border-radius:15px;border=0;"></input>
</div>

<div class="vertAlign"> 
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="search" style="width:100px;height=40px;font-size=20px;"/>
</div>​
```

Then apply this css

```
.vertAlign{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/8ZuVF/) with the result

note: all of your css should be fine as is.  I omitted it in my fiddle so that the solution would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UXRjN/1/

I wrapped the search button around a DIV and added a few minor attributes

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. The button is now to the centre of the box but it's all the way to the right. I guess because of float? I'd like it to be right next to the box. FYI, I realize that the hover id should be #search:hover not submit, previous change in name error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align` CSS property to vertical align the inline elements within the line.